# receive Error code 500 when visiting a cgi file (in c++)

Tags: cgi

I wrote the following code in a file named test.cpp on godaddy web host:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
   cout << "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
   cout << "<html>\n";
   cout << "<head>\n";
   cout << "<title>Hello World - First CGI Program</title>\n";
   cout << "</head>\n";
   cout << "<body>\n";
   cout << "<h2>Hello World! This is my first CGI program</h2>\n";
   cout << "</body>\n";
   cout << "</html>\n";

   return 0;
}
```

And I compile test.cpp on the godaddy host using "g++ test.cpp -o a.cgi".
Then I tried to access the cgi (type "www.XXX.com/a.cgi"), the error code 500 came out. I have no idea what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the permissions of the file using file manager to make it executable
2. try `www.xxx.com/cgi-bin/a.cgi`
3. changing `a.cgi` to `a.cpp` and then check if it works

Comment: Yes, I did it. I used "chmod 755 a.cgi" to change the permissions of the file, but still, it did not work.                                                           However, I tried "cat a.cpp > b.cpp" then move the b.cpp to under the public_html dir and compiled b.cpp using "g++ b.cpp -o b.cgi". It worked! So strange! I wonder why it worked this time